# XNA spritesheet animation

Tags: animation, xna, sprite-sheet

Creating a simple RPG game, first time using XNA.

Trying to get my character to face different ways whenever i move in different directions.

The problem is that when i start up i cant even see my texture, the weird thing is that when i walk over a specific position in the game the whole spritesheet becomes visible, same thing for my AI NPC:s.. It's like they're laying there behind the background and the rectangle i'm moving is transparant (so i can see through the background with it).

FrameWidth and FrameHeight is sent in when i create an instance of the class. (height = 0 (starting from the top of the spritesheet), width = spritesheetwidth / 4 (to get that single sprite out).)

Velocity is the speed of which the character moves.

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        ObjectRectangle = new Rectangle(CurrentFrame * FrameWidth, 0, FrameWidth, FrameHeight);
        Origin = new Vector2(ObjectRectangle.Width / 2, ObjectRectangle.Height / 2);
        Position += Velocity;

        ObjectRectangleX = (int)PositionX;
        ObjectRectangleY = (int)PositionY;

        #region movement
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.A) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.W) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.S))
        {
            AnimateRight(gameTime);
            VelocityX = 2;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.D) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.W) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.S))
        {
            AnimateLeft(gameTime);
            VelocityX = -2;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.A) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.D) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.S))
        {
            AnimateUp(gameTime);
            VelocityY = -2;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.A) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.W) && Pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.D))
        {
            AnimateDown(gameTime);
            VelocityY = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            Velocity = Vector2.Zero;
        }

        Pastkey = Keyboard.GetState();

        #endregion
    }

    #region Animations

    public void AnimateDown(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        CurrentFrame = 2;
    }
    public void AnimateRight(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        CurrentFrame = 3;
    }
    public void AnimateLeft(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        CurrentFrame = 1;
    }
    public void AnimateUp(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        CurrentFrame = 0;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Draw method looks like:

```
    public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

        spriteBatch.Draw(ObjectTexture, Position, ObjectRectangle, Color.White, 0f, Origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        GameList.Add(this);
    }
```

(Ignore the List.Add)

So what i need help with is "locking" the texture to the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines look unneccessary

```
ObjectRectangleX = (int)PositionX;
ObjectRectangleY = (int)PositionY;
```

One thing you might look at is the final parameter in the .Draw call. You have it as 0f right now, that is the layer depth and if that value is lower than your terrain then the terrain will be drawn on top...I think, depends on your spritebatch.begin() arguments. You can read a bit more here where a few more bits are explained about layer depth.
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23619/2d-layerdepth-not-working-xna-4-0

Comment: Changing the layer depth didnt help unfortunately :/
And those two lines moves the rectangle with the Vector so they're very much needed :)

Comment: Which rectangle? The only one I see is ObjectRectangle, which is a source rectangle which is correctly set as 

`ObjectRectangle = new Rectangle(CurrentFrame * FrameWidth, 0, FrameWidth, FrameHeight);`


A source rectangle is relative to the objects position.

Also, could you link to an image of your spritesheet, that might help show any issues.

Comment: http://homepage.lnu.se/student/aw222fu/pics/CurrentSprites.png
This would be the ones, 5th from top is the one for the character :D

Also, that means i can remove those two lines completely?

Comment: Spritesheet looks fine though hard to tell because I'm at work and can't really look properly. Could you upload the code somewhere (or a stripped down version that still has the bug) and I can look at it as it runs?

Comment: homepage.lnu.se/student/aw222fu/pics/PrototypeGame.rar

That should be all of it, also - commenting out those two lines above fixes the sprites but ruins the AI :/

Comment: How exactly did it ruin the Ai? I ran the code by removing those two lines and the sprites drew correctly and the A.I. objects still moved round.

Comment: They move Yes, Unfortunately not towards the player which they're supposed to :D

Comment: Ok, give this a try. Replace your entire enemy movement method with this. I've commented so hopefully you can understand what is happening. [link](http://pastebin.com/mZGjDgu6)

Comment: You rock, sat with this for about 4 days - Thank you! (Oh yeah and it worked :D)

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that you're calculating the values before knowing that frames data.

Moving this code

```
ObjectRectangle = new Rectangle(CurrentFrame * FrameWidth, 0, FrameWidth, FrameHeight);
Origin = new Vector2(ObjectRectangle.Width / 2, ObjectRectangle.Height / 2);
Position += Velocity;

ObjectRectangleX = (int)PositionX;
ObjectRectangleY = (int)PositionY;
```

To the bottom of your update method will give you better results. Also, it doesn't look like you're updating PositionX, or PositionY. You should instead be using Position.X and Position.Y.

Edit -
You're changing the position of the source image. So when you move across the screen your position updates, moving your source rectangle over closer to what it should be.
So simply commenting out the two below lines should fix it.

```
ObjectRectangleX = (int)PositionX;
ObjectRectangleY = (int)PositionY;
```

Edit 2 - Clarification

To fix both the Source Rectangle, and keep the AI working you need to do the following.
In the Update method of both CharacterAnimation.cs and Monster.cs, comment out the two lines

```
ObjectRectangleX = (int)PositionX;
ObjectRectangleY = (int)PositionY;
```

Then in Monster.cs in the Enemymovement(CharacterAnimation hero) method modify these lines (45,46)

```
ObjectcentreX = ObjectRectangle.X + (ObjectTexture.Width / 2);
ObjectcentreY = ObjectRectangle.Y + (ObjectTexture.Height / 2);
```

to become

```
ObjectcentreX = (int)PositionX + (ObjectTexture.Width / 2);
ObjectcentreY = (int)PositionY + (ObjectTexture.Height / 2);
```

Comment: PositionX and PositionY is Position.X and Position.Y, i just made them their own properties incase i'd have to limit one of them. Thanks for the tip of moving though - unfortunately i still can't see my textures :/

Comment: Ah you shouldn't be changing ObjectRectangleX or Y. They should always be the same from your first new Rectangle(CurrentFrame * FrameWidth, 0, FrameWidth, FrameHeight);
That's the source of the sprite sheet.
Try just commenting those two lines out.
ObjectRectangleX = (int)PositionX;
ObjectRectangleY = (int)PositionY;

Comment: Ok yeah, that got the sprites to work but completely ruined the AI (which is moving the monsters) :P So i get to choose if i should see them or if they should move properly.. :D

Comment: Why is the Source Rectangle being used for the AI? You should be using your Position for the AI not the Position of the Source Rectangle.

Comment: Just saw the code below. If you comment out the ObjectRectangleX/Y code and replace the code in the Monster.cs - Enemymovement(CharacterAnimation hero) method with (int)Position.X/Y instead then it should work.

Comment: Where do you mean i should put (int)Position.X/Y? Instead of the whole objectcentre thing?

Comment: still doesnt completely work, they stay about (charactertexture x 2) positions away from the player.. and they only move on the X axis :/ But the sprites does work.